# Regex match full hyperlink only with certain class

Tags: php, regex, dom, hyperlink

I have a string that has some hyperlinks inside. I want to match with regex only certain link from all of them. I can't know if the href or the class comes first, it may be vary.
This is for example a sting:

```
<div class='wp-pagenavi'>
<span class='pages'>Page 1 of 8</span><span class='current'>1</span>
<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2' class='page'>2</a>     
<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/3' class='page'>3</a>ccccc<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/4' class='page'>4</a><a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/5' class='page'>5</a><a href="http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2" class="nextpostslink">»eee</a><span class='extend'>...</span><a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/8' class='last'>lastן »</a>
<a class="cccc">xxx</a>
</div>
```

I want to select from the aboce string only the one that has the class **nextpostslink**
So, the match in this example should return this -

```
<a href="http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2" class="nextpostslink">»eee</a>
```

This regex is the most close I could get -

```
/<a\s?(href=)?('|")(.*)('|") class=('|")nextpostslink('|")>.{1,6}<\/a>/
```

But it is selecting the links from the start of the string. 
I think my problem is in the **(.*)** , but I can't figure out how to change this to select only the needed link.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. What language are you programming in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much better to use a genuine HTML parser for this. Abandon all attempts to use regular expressions on HTML.

Use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $classes = explode(' ', $link->getAttribute('class'));

    if (in_array('nextpostslink', $classes)) {
        // $link has the class "nextpostslink"
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be a big performance hit, I would only suggest this is speed is really not an issue or if further processing will be done.

Comment: @Nicklas Claptrap. (1) DOMDocument is surprisingly fast. (2) Don't optimise prematurely. (3) DOMDocument will *work*, whereas regex *might* work (occasionally).

Comment: I think it will be a bit overkill to instance a new object with all page's html. The page has huge html and this is only a very small part of the page.

Comment: @Maor Using regex on a long string isn't going to have great performance either. Seriously, don't use regex on this. It'll be unreliable, it will break when the HTML changes slightly, and it will give you migraines. Use a tool designed for the job.

Comment: I realized that I can load this only string as a DOMDocument instance, so I don't have to load all page's html, so your method might really be better than regex in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would work in php:

```
/<a[^>]+href=(\"|')([^\"']*)('|\")[^>]+class=(\"|')[^'\"]*nextpostslink[^'\"]*('|\")[^>]*>(.{1,6})<\/a>/m
```

This is of course assuming that the class attribute always comes after the href attribute.

This is a code snippet:

```
$html = <<<EOD
<div class='wp-pagenavi'>
<span class='pages'>Page 1 of 8</span><span class='current'>1</span>
<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2' class='page'>2</a>     
<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/3' class='page'>3</a>ccccc<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/4' class='page'>4</a><a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/5' class='page'>5</a><a href="http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2" class="nextpostslink">»eee</a><span class='extend'>...</span><a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/8' class='last'>lastן »</a>
<a class="cccc">xxx</a>
</div>
EOD;

$regexp = "/<a[^>]+href=(\"|')([^\"']*)('|\")[^>]+class=(\"|')[^'\"]*nextpostslink[^'\"]*('|\")[^>]*>(.{1,6})<\/a>/m";

$matches = array();
if(preg_match($regexp, $html, $matches)) {
    echo "URL: " . $matches[2] . "\n";
    echo "Text: " . $matches[6] . "\n";
}
```

I would however suggest first matching the link and then getting the url so that the order of the attributes doesn't matter:

```
<?php

$html = <<<EOD
<div class='wp-pagenavi'>
<span class='pages'>Page 1 of 8</span><span class='current'>1</span>
<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2' class='page'>2</a>     
<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/3' class='page'>3</a>ccccc<a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/4' class='page'>4</a><a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/5' class='page'>5</a><a href="http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/2" class="nextpostslink">»eee</a><span class='extend'>...</span><a href='http://stv.localhost/channel/political/page/8' class='last'>lastן »</a>
<a class="cccc">xxx</a>
</div>
EOD;

$regexp = "/(<a[^>]+class=(\"|')[^'\"]*nextpostslink[^'\"]*('|\")[^>]*>(.{1,6})<\/a>)/m";

$matches = array();
if(preg_match($regexp, $html, $matches)) {
    $link = $matches[0];
    $text = $matches[4];

    $regexp = "/href=(\"|')([^'\"]*)(\"|')/";
    $matches = array();
    if(preg_match($regexp, $html, $matches)) {
        $url = $matches[2];

        echo "URL: $url\n";
        echo "Text: $text\n";
    }
}
```

You could of course extend the regexp by matching one of the both variants (class first vs href first) but it would be very long and I don't think it would be a performance increase.

Just as a proof of concept I created a regexp that doesn't care about the order:

```
/<a[^>]+(href=(\"|')([^\"']*)('|\")[^>]+class=(\"|')[^'\"]*nextpostslink[^'\"]*(\"|')|class=(\"|')[^'\"]*nextpostslink[^'\"]*(\"|')[^>]+href=(\"|')([^\"']*)('|\"))[^>]*>(.{1,6})<\/a>/m
```

The text will be in group 12 and the URL will be in *either* group 3 or group 10 depending on the order.

Comment: I use php and trying to use the preg_match function. But before that I just do some test with this great regex helper - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to figyre out what is right the expression .

Comment: Great! That expressions seems to be working. But, since this is auto generated html, I can't assume that the href will always bebefore the class. Is there a way to have this expression work for both cases (href comes before or after the class) ?

Comment: Thanks! it looks to be doing the needed process

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're but anyway: it's a bad idea to parse html with regex. Use a xpath implementation in order to reach the desired elements. The following xpath expression would give you all the 'a' elements with class "nextpostlink" :

```
//a[contains(@class,"nextpostslink")]
```

There are loads of xpath info around, since you didn't mention your programming language here goes a quick xpath tutorial using java: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

**Edit:**

php + xpath + html: http://dev.juokaz.com/php/web-scraping-with-php-and-xpath

Answer (score 0):

As the question is to get it by **regex**, here is how `<a\s[^>]*class=["|']nextpostslink["|'][^>]*>(.*)<\/a>`.

It doesn't matter in which order are the attributs and it also consider simple or double quotes.

Check the regex online: https://regex101.com/r/DX03KD/1/

Answer (score -1):

I replaced the (.*) with [^'"]+ as follows:

```
<a\s*(href=)?('|")[^'"]+('|") class=('|")nextpostslink('|")>.{1,6}</a>
```

Note: I tried this with RegEx Buddy so I didnt need to escape the <>'s or /

Comment: I tried this, but now it is matching nothing. I of course escaped all the ' " / . Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.